# How to split coordinates in a string into a list of smaller lists

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I am trying to turn a string of coordinates "(x1, y1), (x2, y2)" into [[x1,y1], [x2,y2]] where all the coordinates are converted into floats as well.

My current code doesn't seem to trim whitespace of the y coordinates nor does it convert the strings into floats.

```
coordinates = "(-89.38477, 26.6671), (-89.38477, 27.13737), (-88.81348, 27.13737), (-88.81348, 26.6671)"
for x in re.findall("\((.*?)\)", coordinates):
        final_coordinates = x.lstrip().split(',')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option could be to enclose the `coordinates` into square brackets and use [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> coordinates = "(-89.38477, 26.6671), (-89.38477, 27.13737), (-88.81348, 27.13737), (-88.81348, 26.6671)"
>>>
>>> data = list(literal_eval(coordinates))
>>> data
[(-89.38477, 26.6671), (-89.38477, 27.13737), (-88.81348, 27.13737), (-88.81348, 26.6671)]
```

Comment: this would not work unfortunately, I need the inner brackets to be square as well, the requirement of the json I need to POST to the endpoint.

Comment: How about `list(literal_eval(coordinates ))`?

Comment: @user4659009 ok, you can follow what timgeb suggested. Or, you can replace `(` with `[` and `)` with `]` in the input data.